# Does this proof of convergence work?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions

I need an analysis about the convergence of a sequence of measurable functions. I have written up a proof but I am not sure if it works. Would be grateful if someone could give it a once-over.

Part 1) Assuming that for a given sequence of measurable functions on some measure space $(S, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ such that $v_n \rightarrow v$ in the measure $\mu$, and for some $r > 0$ we have that:
\begin{equation}\int|v_n|^rd\mu\rightarrow\int|v|^rd\mu\end{equation}
(these integrals have been assumed to exist), we wish to prove that:
\begin{equation}
    \int|v_n - v|^r d\mu\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}
We know that the convergence in measure means that there's a subsequence such that $v_{n_l}\rightarrow v$ $\mu$-a.e.. This implies that $|v_{n_l} - v|^p \rightarrow 0$, for all $p>0$.
The idea then is to dominate the sequence $|v_{n_l} - v|^p$ by some $u_{n_l}$, such that $u_{n_l} \rightarrow u$, and $\int u_{n_l} \rightarrow \int u<\infty$ and get the conclusion by the \textbf{generalised Dominated convergence Theorem}. We begin with noticing that for $r\in(0,\infty)$:
\begin{equation}
    |v_{n_l} - v| \le |v_{n_l}| + |v| \implies |v_{n_l} - v|^r \le (|v_{n_l}|+|v|)^r
\end{equation}
\textbf{Case 1:} We first assume that $r\in[1,\infty)$. Then from the fact that for non-negative $a$ and $b$: $(a+b)^r \le 2^ra^r + 2^rb^r$, and the bound just before:

\begin{equation}|v_{n_l} - v|^r\le 2^r(|v_{n_l}|^r+|v|^r)\end{equation}
Now we set $u_{n_l}\overset{\text{def}}{=} 2^r(|v_{n_l}|^r+|v|^r)$. It is obvious that $u_{n_l}\rightarrow 2^{r+1}|v|^r$ $\mu$-a.e., so we define $u\overset{\text{def}}{=} 2^{r+1}|v|^r$. Finally note that:
$$\int u_{n_l} = 2^r\left(\int |v_{n_l}|^r + \int |v|^r\right)\rightarrow 2^{r+1}\int|v|^r < \infty$$
\textbf{Case 2:} Assume now that $r\in (0,1)$. Now with the inequality: $(a + b)^r\le a^r + b^r$, and again (5.1), we have:
$$|v_{n_l}-v|^r \le |v_{n_l}|^r+|v|^r$$
Finally by setting $u_{n_l}$, as the right hand side of the above and $u\overset{\text{def}}{=} 2|v|^r$, we are able to get the exact same conclusion. We have shown that the hypothesis for the Generalised dominated convergence theorem are met in either case.

Part 2) Given two sequences of measurable functions $v_n$ and $u_n$ on a  ameasure space $(S,\mathcal{G},\mu)$ such that $v_n\rightarrow v$ and $u_n \rightarrow u$, and for some conjugate pair of exponents $q, q'\in(1,\infty)$ for which it is true that:
$$\int|v_n|^q\;d\mu \rightarrow \int|v|^q\;d\mu \mbox{   and }\int|u_n|^{q'}d\mu\rightarrow \int|u|^{q'}d\mu$$
We want to show that:
$$\int |v_nu_n - vu|\;d\mu\rightarrow 0$$
To this end we consider the following bound which comes from the triangle inequality and H"{o}lder's Inequality:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\int |v_nu_n - vu|\;d\mu &= \int |v_nu_n - v_nu + v_nu - vu|\;d\mu \\
&\le \int |v_nu_n - v_nu|\;d\mu + \int |v_nu - vu|\;d\mu \\
&= \int |v_n||u_n - u|\;d\mu + \int |u||v_n - v|\;d\mu \\
&= \left(\int |v_n|^q\;d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\left(\int|u_n - u|^{q'}\;d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q'}} + \left(\int |u|^{q'}\;d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q'}}\left(\int|v_n - v|^{q}\;d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Then the required result follows from taking the limit.

Comment: You lost me on your second part, I do not know why you want to show $\int |v_n u_n - vu| d\mu \rightarrow 0$. I expected this second part to relate to showing that, given you know convergence holds on a subsequence, it also holds on the whole sequence.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I copy and pasted the LaTeX file without checking the editing. What I actually need is the bit $\int|v_nu_n - uv|d\mu\rightarrow 0$. For that conclusion, I needed $\int|v_n - v|d\mu\rightarrow 0$ (unless there's a more a straightforward way?). I will edit the question to make it more readable.

Comment: So it seems parts 1 and 2 are completely different problems. However, in part 1, at most you have concluded you get convergence over a subsequence, you have not mentioned how convergence over those indices $n_i$ is useful.

Comment: I see what you mean. If I had the stronger hypothesis of a.s. convergence on the sequences then I could do away with the subsequence and the proof would work, right? Any clue on how to make it work with just the hypothesis of convergence in measure.

Comment: I did not delve much into your proof but I find that most of the important elements are already presented. That is a good sign.

Comment: Then if you need the a.s convergence for your demonstration, please remind yourself that you can always transform the hypothesis of "convergence in measure" to "a.s convergence" by considering appropriate subsequences of $(v_n)$

Comment: So in my proof, I did take the subsequence along which $v_n$ converges to $v$ almost everywhere and deduced (adequately I hope) that $\int |v_n - v|^r d\mu \rightarrow 0$. But as Michael has pointed out this proves convergence along this subsequence only. Would it suffice then to note that $\lim\int |v_n - v|^r d\mu < \infty$ due to the bounds already deduced in my proof and conclude from elementary analysis that because the limit exists it must be the same as the limit attained along the subsequence?

Comment: @Anonymous : I believe the missing step is to first take any subsequence $v_{n_k}$ for which $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} \int |v_{n_k}-v|^rd\mu$  exists.  Now use your existing argument (which passes to a sub-subsequence) to conclude the limit must be zero. So the limit must be zero over any subsequence that converges to a limit, so the limsup and liminf must both be zero.  Or you can streamline the argument to simply assume $v_{n_k}$ is a sequence that achieves $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int |v_n-v|^rd\mu$.